# Where can I download WPF Performance Suite for Windows 8

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, windows-8

The WPF Performance Suite is described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx#installing_the_wpf_performance_suite

-> how can I install it on Windows 8?

(the Windows 7 SDK can't be installed and the Windows 8 SDK contains Performance tools such as GPUView but not the WPF profilers "Perforator" and "Visual Profiler".

I googled several hours for it but didn't find anything.

Comment: WPF perf suite for Windows 7.1 still seems to be the latest. Direct download link: http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/6/A/A6AC035D-DA3F-4F0C-ADA4-37C8E5D34E3D/setup/WinSDKPerformanceToolKit_amd64/wpt_x64.msi Also fix for Visual Profiler: http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/8/9/189A7832-49D8-4978-85E8-3DFFF44E6C04/WpfPerf_timezone_patch.msp (choose "repair")

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ok, I have it running under Windows 8, but afaik only for framework 4.

[Download the tools](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/6/A/A6AC035D-DA3F-4F0C-ADA4-37C8E5D34E3D/setup/WinSDKPerformanceToolKit_amd64/wpt_x64.msi) (link borrowed from Athari above)

Install and it test. Select visual profiler and attach to a process. If it doesn't appear to work, download [this patch from MS](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=21042).

After installing the patch I now have it working again. This is on Windows 8 pro running on a Dell XPS 17 i7 based machine.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Would have preferred a link to the download page though, not the file :)

Answer (score 6):

it comes as a pack of Windows Performance Toolkit (WPT) v5 for Windows 8
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wptkv5/thread/090ed47a-f253-4c5a-8dc8-a7923e839815

here is the download

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30652

Comment: I downloaded that (the MSI for WPF Performance Suite is the same as in the Windows 8 SDK) but it doesn't include Perforator and Visual Profiler. Maybe I should change the question to "where can I download Perforator / Visual Profiler"

Comment: I think we are looking for WPF performance suit not windows performance suit. !!

Answer (score 4):

I managed to get everything downloaded and working under `Windows 10` with a `.NET 4.5 WPF app`.

- Follow instructions from Microsoft at [Where to Download WPF Performance Suite? (Perforator, Visual Profiler)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kirillosenkov/2016/04/05/where-to-download-wpf-performance-suite-perforator-visual-profiler/). You need to install both the app, and its timezone patch.
- You must run the WPF profile app `before` you run the target app.
- Try running the target app as `Administrator`. It needs elevated privileges, or else it will not appear in the `Select Process` dialog.
- If you cannot run the target app as `Administrator`, then you can still use 
  `Actions..Launch Process` to launch it.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2015 comes with "Timeline", which by my estimation roughly provides the same features as Visual profiler. It can profile WPF on .net4+, including 4.5, 4.6.

It can be started by

> To profile a WPF application in Visual Studio 2015 CTP 5, open the Performance and Diagnostics hub from the Debug -> Start Diagnostic Tools Without Debugging (ALT+F2) menu. Select the Application Timeline tool and click Start (You can also run the CPU Usage tool alongside the Application Timeline tool).

(Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpf/2015/01/16/new-ui-performance-analysis-tool-for-wpf-applications/)