# How do you install the WPF Performance Suite in Windows 8.1?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, performance, windows-8.1

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa969767%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#installing_the_wpf_performance_suite) clearly describes the process of installing the WPF Performance Suite, but with a HUGE caveat for Windows 8.1 users.

Process:

- After the Windows SDK is installed, on the Start menu, select All Programs, Microsoft Windows SDK v7.1, and then Tools.
- Under Tools, click Install Windows Performance Tool Kit. The setup wizard appears.

So, here are some of my questions:

- First, there is a [Windows 8.1 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx). This ***does not*** contain the WPF performance suite?
- Second, they removed the old start menu and I don't see the aforementioned installation link in Windows 8.1...so if I have the 7.1 SDK, uh, ***where*** is the installer located?
- Third, does the WPF Performance Suite from 7.1 ***even work*** with/in windows 8.1...?

This is **so annoying** and its driving me crazy.

Comment: I've you tried the steps outlined in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469206/where-can-i-download-wpf-performance-suite-for-windows-8?rq=1

Comment: @sous2817 You know what, I went to that link earlier and gave it a go, but the tools kept crashing on me...so just now I had finished uninstalling all my older SDKs and reinstalling 7.1 and then downloaded that file from the link provided and it finally started to work. Thanks.

Comment: @Alexandru: Do you know how to use the WPF Performance Suite with a .NET 4.5 app? I would appreciate you if you take a look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33468572/3345644).

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov Yes, so actually, it turns out that Visual Studio (later versions) have this built in, so right now with VS 2013, I can create a new profiler session by opening up Visual Studio, and from the top menu there is an Analyze drop down, just go to Analyze -> Profiler -> Attach/Detach to attach it to an existing debug process. But sidenote: its really shitty, I would recommend using this profiler instead: http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/

Answer (score 10):

I managed to get everything working under `Windows 10` with a `.NET 4.5 WPF app`.

I assume that this also applies to `Windows 8.1`. If it doesn't, you always have the fallback option to upgrade to Windows 10.

- Follow instructions from Microsoft at [Where to Download WPF Performance Suite? (Perforator, Visual Profiler)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kirillosenkov/2016/04/05/where-to-download-wpf-performance-suite-perforator-visual-profiler/). You need to install both the app, and its timezone patch.
- You must run the WPF profile app `before` you run the target app.
- Try running the target app as `Administrator`. It needs elevated privileges, or else it will not appear in the `Select Process` dialog.
- If you cannot run the target app as `Administrator`, then you can still use 
  `Actions..Launch Process` to launch it.

Comment: The timezone patch download link no longer works but it is available here: https://web.archive.org/web/20210118105730/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kirillosenkov/where-to-download-wpf-performance-suite-perforator-visual-profiler

Comment: The link given by bds did not work either for me, but the following one did work (using blogs.msdn.com instead of learn.microsoft.com): https://web.archive.org/web/20190118054809/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kirillosenkov/2016/04/05/where-to-download-wpf-performance-suite-perforator-visual-profiler/

Comment: Or try to use this direct link to the patch file: https://web.archive.org/web/20200727114215/https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/8/9/189A7832-49D8-4978-85E8-3DFFF44E6C04/WpfPerf_timezone_patch.msp