# Is there a WPF Performance Suite for .NET 4.0 for XP or Windows 2008 R2?

Tags: wpf, performance, .net-4.0, windows-xp-sp3

I'm currently developing an WPF application using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional on the .NET Framework 4. Using two machines, one an XP 32 Bit machine, and the other on a Windows 2008 R2 machine.

When ever I google around the WPF Performance Suite it links purely to the MSDN page around the suite. [The link below].
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx#installing_the_wpf_performance_suite

The only other post that is a similar question is around getting it to work with Windows 8. [The link below].
[Where can I download WPF Performance Suite for Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469206/where-can-i-download-wpf-performance-suite-for-windows-8)

Is there a WPF Performance Suite for .NET 4.0 for XP or Windows 2008 R2?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. As such, I have voted to close your question.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel this way but I was under the impression that stackoverflow was a site to ask question about programming. Which programming to me extends to not just that of the implementation, but testing and debugging to name just a few.

Maybe I could have been more concise with my question when asking for the specific software I am looking for rather than recommending a similar suite to limit more opinionated answers.

Comment: Let's be clear about this... I did not make this rule. In fact, the exact text in my earlier comment was written by StackOverflow and has come about through extensive discussions on the Meta StackOverflow website by the community. It's the community that decides these things, so by all means add a new question to that website, noting your displeasure of the current system. Alternatively, try asking a specific programming question, rather than asking for a tool/suite.

Comment: I'm assuming I read the same discussion on the meta stackoverflow site where the same answer states "There are exceptions, but questions asking about a specific tool can usually be made to be acceptable."

I am asking about a specific tool (in the title at least).

Comment: while I do understand your frustration, you'd be much better off if you just accept that this is *not* the place to ask for *a tool, library or favorite off-site resource*. Use another site for that. There's no point in trying to convince me of anything, because even if I *did* remove my close vote, you'd still have to convince every other StackOverflow member and let's face it... that's not going to happen. You see... you have already received two other close votes from other community users who are aware of the rules of this site.

Comment: I am not asking for a recommendation of tool. I am asking for advice about a specific issue with a tool, I have already chosen. This is allowed. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139399/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question. This should clear things up for you. Also this discussion would be better suited for meta stackoverflow, instead of giving non-constructive comments here.

Comment: Why are you *still* arguing??? You have your answer already. And what do you mean by *I am not asking for a recommendation of tool*? Your question clearly asks *So does anyone know if there is a similar suite for .NET 4.0 Framework, and that would work on XP 32Bit or Windows 2008 R2?* Look... at the end of the day, I didn't make the rules, I just follow them. We clearly disagree and that's fine, but I'm not going to retract my close vote. I added the initial comment to help you, just so that you'd know why... I didn't expect all this nonsense. As far as I am concerned, this discussion is over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 7.1 of the Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4 includes the Performance Suite and is compatible with both these versions of Windows and .Net 4. See [Windows SDK release blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/archive/2010/05/25/released-windows-sdk-for-windows-7-and-net-framework-4.aspx)