# Where can I download the full Microsoft SDK 7 to get WPF Performance Suite?

Tags: wpf, windows-7, .net-4.0

I have been googling for what feels like an age to find a direct download of the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4 in order to get the WPF Performance Suite.

If I got to the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 download page, it only downloads a down-loader which doesn't work for me. As I need to put the installer onto a machine that is disconnected from the internet.

I also managed to find an ISO image, but again that doesn't work for me, again I have no DVD drive on this machine.

(https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)

Someone posted a direct link asking a similar questions for Windows 8, I am just hoping someone else has one for x86.

[Where can I download WPF Performance Suite for Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469206/where-can-i-download-wpf-performance-suite-for-windows-8)

Comment: I posted now both links. I overlooked that you needed the x86 one

Answer (score 0):

I saw this 1 week ago in a [Microsoft blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kirillosenkov/2016/04/05/where-to-download-wpf-performance-suite-perforator-visual-profiler/).

Download the WPT installer [x86](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/6/A/A6AC035D-DA3F-4F0C-ADA4-37C8E5D34E3D/setup/WinSDKPerformanceToolKit/wpt_x86.msi) [x64](https://download.microsoft.com/download/A/6/A/A6AC035D-DA3F-4F0C-ADA4-37C8E5D34E3D/setup/WinSDKPerformanceToolKit_amd64/wpt_x64.msi) and select here the WPF Profiler:

[image]

Now you should [apply this patch](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/8/9/189A7832-49D8-4978-85E8-3DFFF44E6C04/WpfPerf_timezone_patch.msp) (select `Reapir`).